# JavaFX can't set WebView in FXML file

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-webengine

When i try to run my application i get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at WebOpenController.<init>(WebOpenController.java:19)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:438)
at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:923)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:967)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:216)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2701)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2521)
... 22 more
```

Line 19 is this private WebEngine engine = view.getEngine();

and this is the class:

```
public class WebOpenController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private WebView view;

private String link = "http://google.com";

private WebEngine engine = view.getEngine();

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    engine.load(link);
}
```

But when i do WebView view = new WebView it will work but it wont open the page on startup

and i did set the fx-id in scenebuilder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to retrieve the web engine after the webview has been instantiated. Note that `initialize()` will be called *after* the contents from the fxml file have been completely loaded, so that's where you should do this. You can read about this [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers).

This will work:

```
@FXML
private WebView view;

private String link = "http://google.com";

private WebEngine engine;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    engine = view.getEngine();
    engine.load(link);
}
```